# Tomcat 8.5.4 javax.naming.NameNotFoundException

Tags: java, tomcat

I am developing a web application with Tomcat 8.5.4. I'm using a properties configured as Resource. So, my $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml contains

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="properties/global" auth="Container" type="java.util.Properties" />
</GlobalNamingResources>
```

The META-INF/context.xml of my webapp has

```
<Context antiResourceLocking="true" path="/mywebapp">
  <ResourceLink global="properties/global" name="properties/global" type="java.util.Properties"/>
</Context>
```

I'm looking up the resource as follow

```
Context initContext = new InitialContext();
Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
(Properties) envContext.lookup("properties/global");
```

However, I'm getting the exception

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [properties/global] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [properties].
```

What's wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I believe `META-INF/context.xml` is only used when the webapp is *initially* deployed. It is then copied to `.../conf/Catalina/localhost/mywebapp.xml`. Check that file, since it is probably missing the `<ResourceLink>`.

Comment: But this exception blocks the application deployment. So, there is no any `../conf/Catalina/localhost/mywebapp.xml`

Comment: How can the exception block deployment? The exception occurs when your code is executed, i.e. when the webapp is started (your code runs during webapp initialization) or some time later, and the webapp must be deployed before it is started.

Comment: Really, it doesn't make sense an exception blocking an application deployment. I've realized the files in CATALINA_BASE have not been updated after my changes on files in CATALINA_HOME. How to force this updating?